Does anyone recognize this electrical panel or know what brand of breakers are acceptable?
I need to add a 15amp 240v double breaker to an outdoor subpanel. The only identification number on the panel is on a small sticker in the box that says Class-CTL ENCLOSED PANELBOX No. EU 387722. (I don't see any info about this number online.) The breakers in the box are a mix of 4 brands: 100 amp main double breaker Challenger Type C2100; 60 amp double breaker for a 5 hp pump Westinghouse BR260R; Cutler-Hammer Type BR215 Type C215; Challenger type C120; Connecticut type TB. What brand breaker can I use for a new circuit?


I can't see your image. Please post to an image host and update the link.

Readable close-ups of the labels on the current breakers, and possibly of the UL listing sticker in the upper right corner, might help resolve this question.

OK, thanks. I just uploaded the photos to dropbox. The link to the UL listing sticker is: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/44p2ru5ks0qwewfdtinf3/IMG_7672.jpg?rlkey=ud6ywjc78t99fdmeys954hfhq&dl=0

And the breaker photo links are:https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/34df4au3o3swmf1udqxux/IMG_7673.HEIC?rlkey=zv7tdojf5qclual965gp6afwv&dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/yhjgvnafun1h7fij90oxo/IMG_7674.HEIC?rlkey=hq60lw5zjswg9kwgwkj0czgdd&dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/xapypi4jcyr1vv64ffir1/IMG_7675.HEIC?rlkey=bl51yfovpmbm75t69fwv6og7j&dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/vsat1ht4ey5fvctdwemn0/IMG_7676.HEIC?rlkey=1y4f64bl6viou8g6d4zw9xigs&dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/myy538z1o7hovbora02il/IMG_7677.HEIC?rlkey=m65t975kdkaef3d6dsrq03lj0&dl=0

The panel's probably an Eaton BR, so use BR breakers
From the existing breakers (although the off-brand TB breaker and the Challenger breakers should be swapped for BR counterparts, in addition to the Murray breaker that snuck in somehow), the metal backpan design, the notched stabs, the single-size (vs. "Swiss cheese") neutrals, and the back bonding strap, I'm fairly sure that's consistent with a BR panel, vs. a Murray (which'd have "Swiss cheese" neutrals), a Homeline (which'd have a polymer backpan), or a Siemens (which never had its neutral intertie set up to strap around the back from edge to edge the way pre-PoN BRs did).

Just to note for the new people, including OP: Many Challenger breakers had known problems but BR is listed as a replacement - so the mix & match in that sense is backwards (and wrong) but not far from legit, except that the Challenger breakers aren't reliable and therefore should be replaced and the Connecticut breakers are Challenger exact replacement but with the same problems and should also be replaced. The Murray is a good breaker but in the wrong type of panel and has to be replaced for that reason. But basic breakers (as opposed to GFCI/AFCI) are inexpensive so just do it.

Those screws that penetrate through the dead front for adjusting the depth of the bussing forward to the dead front make me think it's an ITE EQ which would make Siemens the heir of the Listing.

Normally I like to use the specific brand specified, but this might be a good application to use Eaton Classified breakers that are cross listed for most panels. Eaton UL Classified breakers are designed and tested to be both mechanically and electrically interchangeable with circuit breakers manufactured by General Electric, Thomas & Betts, ITE/Siemens, Murray, Crouse-Hinds, and Square D/Homeline.
